# grails - Why is it suggested to put CRUD code inside of a service rather than in the controller itself?

Tags: grails, service

Why is it suggested to put CRUD code inside of a service rather than in the controller itself?

Answer (score 1):

Besides soc, reusability, testability etc. i can additionally see the following more technical reason:

Per default, each method in a Grails service is implicitly (or explicilty with `@Transactional`, see [0]) wrapped in a transaction. Whenever an (unchecked!) exception occurs, the transaction is automatically rolled back by Spring.

As CRUD code often modifies aggregates consisting of multiple domain objects, it is recommended (besides gaining reusability etc.) to move this code into "transaction script" [1] service methods to let Grails/Spring manage transaction handling.

[0] http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html

[1] http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html

Answer (score 0):

If your "CRUD code" means application logic.

Grails encourages to write application logic in service because
1. separation of concern
2. reuseable